# Can't use some of L SDK features

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adt, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to use the new Activity transitions in the new SDK.

I tried this line:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
```

But the problem is that `Window` doesn't include `FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS`.

I also tried this line:

```
getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
```

And `Explode` class doesn't exist...

I already set my project to be compiled with L SDK (android-L) and use the new SDK tools (20.0.0)

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.tester'
        minSdkVersion 'L'
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get that error on compile or at runtime? Where are you executing that code?

Comment: I get this code as a syntax error, those classes don't exist. (I'm using Android Studio)

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Added build.gradle.

Comment: I have the exact same issue with Android Studio Beta... I open the sample project https://github.com/romainguy/google-io-2014, compile and run on emulator, but Android Studio says that some (new L preview) classes doesn't exist ....

Comment: I made a fresh new install of Android Studio and now all works fine!

Comment: @sabadow I already tried it, didn't work.

Comment: setting Build Target to API level 21 fixes it. But I wonder what will happen when I use the app on 4.4.2... we'll see

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are not including the L SDK library in your build path. 
Are the libraries listed as dependency of your project?

Comment: `com.android.support:support-v4:+` is the only library listed in my dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.

If that doesn't work, you can try deleting ~/.AndroidStudioBeta (or ~/.AndroidStudioPreview, whichever you are using). It will clear all your settings so be prepared for that, but this solved the issue in my case.

For Mac, clear:
~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioBeta

Comment: Tried both solutions, didn't work as well. I noticed something, in the editor I control-clicked `Window` so it would take me to the `Window` class source, and I noticed that it uses API-Level 20. It should use API-Level L, doesn't it?

Comment: It should be like [this](http://i.imgur.com/9JvRKJH.png). In your /sdk/platforms directory, do you have an 'android-L' folder? Perhaps delete the L packages from the SDK manager and reinstall. Repeat the above steps to reset caches if necessary.

Comment: I do have 'android-L' folder. And I already tried to re-install the packages from the SDK Manager.