# Can't use Lollipop specific classes in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm having problems with `Lollipop` specific classes in a `minSdk 21` project.
This is my `gradle.build`

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mypackage"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

When I try to use `UsageStatsManager` I get a `'Cannot resolve symbol UsageStatsManager'` error from `Android Studio`.
Or if I use `Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE`/`Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE` the constant isn't found.

This is an example class that gives me these errors.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager;
import android.app.job.JobScheduler;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    JobScheduler mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
}
```

In this case even the `import` for `UsageStatsManager` fails with the error `'Cannot resolve symbol UsageStatsManager'`, while the `JobScheduler` is found (but I can't use it because I have no `Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE`)

I've downloaded `android-21` platform from the `SDK Manager`, I have both the `source` and the `SDK`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Something from an old installation of Android Studio was causing problems, so I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24464681/1354302) and deleted the caches. It now works.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to `JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE`, that's [a known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77719) and can be overcome temporarily via a `@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")` annotation until you get your hands on a newer Android Studio.

With regards to `android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager`, though, I can import that fine on Android Studio 0.8.9 with `compileSdkVersion 21`.

Comment: Ok, the JobScheduler problem is gone, but I still can't figure out how to import UsageStatsService. I'm on Android Studio 0.9.0

(Great talk at droidconUK)

Comment: @DavidCorsalini: I updated my answer -- I have no problem importing that class, so I am not quite certain what may be wrong in your environment. Make sure that you have the latest version of the SDK Platform for API Level 21 downloaded in the SDK Manager. And I'm glad that you liked the conference presentation!